# MS Access VBA QueryDef - With Block variable not set error

Tags: vba, ms-access-2010

When using QueryDef i receive the following error "Object
variable or With block variable not set". when i copy the output of strSQL to a new Query it works fine. Please assist in the solution for this error.

The error occurs when running the following line;

```
Set qryDef = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQueryName, strSQL)
```

See Entire code below

```
Private Sub ComboReclassify_AfterUpdate()

Dim dbs As Database
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strQueryName As String
Dim qryDef As QueryDef

strQueryName = "qryST_ReclassifyAttribute"

Dim attr As String
Dim ValueID As Integer
attr = [Forms]![frm_tblST_AttributesReclassification]![ComboItemAttributes]
ValueID = [Forms]![frm_tblST_AttributesReclassification]![ComboReclassify]

strSQL = "UPDATE dbo_tblST_DepartmentsAttributes SET  " & (attr) & " = " & ValueID & " WHERE dbo_tblST_DepartmentsAttributes.id = 1"

Set qryDef = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQueryName, strSQL)

DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryST_ReclassifyAttribute"

End Sub
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seemed to have missed setting the dbs object.

```
Private Sub ComboReclassify_AfterUpdate()
    Dim dbs As Database
    Dim strSQL As String
    Dim strQueryName As String
    Dim qryDef As QueryDef

    strQueryName = "qryST_ReclassifyAttribute"

    Dim attr As String
    Dim ValueID As Integer
    attr = [Forms]![frm_tblST_AttributesReclassification]![ComboItemAttributes]
    ValueID = [Forms]![frm_tblST_AttributesReclassification]![ComboReclassify]

    strSQL = "UPDATE dbo_tblST_DepartmentsAttributes SET  " & (attr) & " = " & ValueID & " WHERE dbo_tblST_DepartmentsAttributes.id = 1"

    'You have not set the dbs object. That is the problem
    Set dbs = CurrentDB
    Set qryDef = dbs.CreateQueryDef(strQueryName, strSQL)

    DoCmd.OpenQuery "qryST_ReclassifyAttribute"
End Sub
```

Once you set it. It should work as normal !